# Python value error(ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

Iam getting an value error(ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 
   2, got 1) at the line for file,file2 in files,files2: any idea how to handle 
   this

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
import glob
directory1= r'L:path'
directory2= r'L:path'
files=glob.glob(directory1 + "\*.xls")
files2=glob.glob(directory2 + "\*.xlsx")
target=pd.read_excel('L:file.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
target2=pd.read_excel('L:file.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
for file,file2 in files,files2:
    df= pd.read_excel(file,index_col=None, header=0)
    df1 = df[:-1]
    df2=pd.read_excel(file2,index_col=None, header=0)
    df3 = pd.Series(delta.days for delta in (df2['dt1']- df2['Dt2']))
    Average=df1['dt'].mean()
    Median=df1['dt'].median()
    val=20
    Average_Var=df3.mean()
    Median_Var=df3.median()
    val1=10
    date=target.iloc[-1]
    date=target2.iloc[-1]
    df05= date['week']+timedelta(days=7)
    df06=date['week']+timedelta(days=7)
    sa=pd.Series([df05,Average,Median,val],index=['week','Average Handling 
    Time','Median Handling Time','Target'])
    sas=pd.Series([df06,Average_Var,Median_Var,val1],index=['Week','Average 
    Handling Time','Median Handling Time','Target'])
    df20=target.append(sa,ignore_index=True,verify_integrity=True)
    df30=target2.append(sas,ignore_index=True,verify_integrity=True)
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('L:path\file.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
writer1=pd.ExcelWriter('L:path\file.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
df20.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)
df30.to_excel(writer1,sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
writer1.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want …

```
for file,file2 in zip(files,files2):
```

… instead of …

```
for file,file2 in files,files2:
```

Comment: I would mention that using `file` is a bad idea when it comes to variable names.

Comment: this works fine, thanks...